# Disable Delve Per User PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, powershell, office-365

Is there a way using PowerShell to disable Delve on a per user basis?

On the settings cog on the About Me page for Delve I can see an option to turn Delve off. This setting only applies to my account.

As an admin I need to apply this setting for all users.

Comment: you want to turn of delve for all users ?

Comment: I want to control the setting that the user themselves uses to turn delve on or off. It’s under About Me - Settings Cog - Settings- Feature Settings / Turn sharing on or off. I do not want to turn off Office Graph which is the only current way to disable Delve.

Comment: Did you try from the admin center, go to the SharePoint admin center.
Select Settings.
Under Office graph, select Don’t allow access to the Office graph.

Comment: @Sara yes but we don’t want to disable for everyone - only for some users.