# Is there a way using PowerShell or CSOM to disable Delve

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

Is there a way using PowerShell or CSOM to disable Delve on a per user basis?

On the settings in AboutMe page for Delve I can see an option to turn Delve off. This setting only applies to my account.

As an admin I need to apply this setting for all users.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to disable for all user, you can follow below steps:

1. go to the SharePoint admin center.
2. Select Settings. Under Office graph
3. select Don’t allow access to the Office graph

[Ref](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/219596/disable-delve-per-user-powershell)

Comment: Thanks for your reply Anil. But I wanted Delve to be disabled for few users and not for everyone.